# Как перемножить матрицы,хранящиеся в одномерных массивах?

Tags: c, алгоритм

Хочу перемножить две двумерные матрицы размерами N*N,которые хранятся в одномерных  массивах.
Но результат получается неверным.
Как сделать индексацию верной?

```
x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
if (x >= N || y >= N)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
        {
            c[x + y * N] += a[x + i * N] * b[i + y * N];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Даю совет - чтоб было легче, определите, скажем, макрос для перевода двух индексов в один - типа

```
#define  num(row,col)  ((col) + (row)*N)
```

Тогда ваше перемножение будет записываться легко и просто:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k)
            sum += a[num(i,k)]*b[num(k,j)];
        c[num(i,j)] = sum;
    }
```

Если очень хочется - можно, конечно, развернуть макрос в выражение прямо в коде, но какой в этом смысл? Программы надо писать так, чтоб было легче человеку, а не машине...

Answer (score 2):

Для вычисления одного элемента матрицы-результата, надо сложить `N` (не `N*N`) произведений элементов матриц-множителей.

```
c[i,j] = sum(a[i,k] * b[k,j]), where 0 <= k < N

m[i,j] = M[i*N + j], m - two-dimensional array, M - one-dimensional array
```